# Debounce an async method

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs2, lodash, debouncing

**Goal —**

Add real-time validation to input with *only the XHR part of that validation being debounced*.

**Problem —**

Adding `debounce` to `valueExists()` breaks `await`. Without `debounce`, it `await`s properly.

How should this be handled?

```
methods: {
  async validate () {
    let local_errors = [];

    if (!!this.value && !this.$data.alpha_dash.test(this.value)) {
      local_errors.push('Invalid character');
    }

    if (!!this.value && await this.valueExists()) {
      local_errors.push('Already used');
    }

    return local_errors;
  },

  valueExists: _.debounce(function () {
    return axios.get(route('organization.slug.exists', { slug: this.value }))
      .then(response => {
        return false;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return true;
      });
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect `valueExists` to return when the debouncing hits?

Comment: A boolean once the promise is resolved.

Comment: Debouncing works by *not* calling the function. So which promise do you mean?

Comment: Which library are you using for that `debounce` method, Underscore? Lodash?

Comment: Lodash. I'm referring to the promise that is axios inside `valueExists()`. I might have a conflict simply by expecting `validate()` to execute on each keystroke while `valueExists()` is debounced. Perhaps I should debounce `validate()` instead?

Comment: Yes, debouncing `validate` (or rather, the function that calls it and uses the `localerrors`) might be the simplest solution.

Comment: The [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) say that "*Subsequent calls to the debounced function return the result of the last func invocation.*" but by default, the function is called on the trailing edge - so there simply is no promise yet during the first few calls.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll change my approach.

Comment: @Bergi although I read the docs the importance of that line didn't click. Thanks so much for pointing that out - makes perfect sense why it doesn't work now.

Answer (score -3):

adding async to the debounced function should work:

```
valueExists: _.debounce(async function () {
    await axios.get(route('organization.slug.exists', { slug: this.value }))
      .then(response => {
        return false;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return true;
      });
  }, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks. What happens now is that the first time `validateLocally()` gets called, `valueExists()` is still `null`. It eventually does return the boolean once the promise is resolved, but I have to call `validateLocally()` a second time in order to see it.

Comment: you could use a default false value for the initialized component what will change once the promise is resolved? If i follow correctly

Comment: Yes, but if it is returning `true`, I still won't know it until the next cycle.

Comment: Why? this does just the same thing his original code is doing (he's returning the promise).